# banner location iOS 7

Tags: ios7, iad, banner, banner-ads

I'm struggling to make banner ads work properly in my iOS 7 app for the iPad.

Per the Apple Developer's guide, I

1)linked the iAd Framework,
2)imported the iAd header to my controller.h file, and
3) enabled canDisplayBannerAds = YES in the controller.m file.

When I run either (in simulator or on iPad), it displays the banners properly at the bottom of the screen in portrait mode.

However, when I turn to landscape mode, it displays the banners along the left side of the screen, as if it were portrait mode.  I cannot seem to figure out how to make it display along the bottom of the screen in landscape mode?